# When should we use the noun plural?

Tags: grammaticality, reading-aloud

1. 0.9 meters
2. 1.0 meters
3. 1.1 meters

I thought if we want to use the plural, the number of the noun should be 2 or more than 2.

So Why should***"0.9 meters" and "1.0 meters"***  use "meters " not "meter"?

Answer (score 1):

You use the plural when the number is **not 1**, and not a fraction with numerator **1**. So you say *"one quarter meter"* and   *"0.25 meters".*

For fractions with larger numerators, you would generally say *"two thirds **of a** meter"*. You should do the same thing for fractions with numerator **1** which aren't common: *"one seventeenth **of a** meter"*. (What does "common" mean? Certainly 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/10, and probably a few more. You can use the *"of a"* form for common fractions as well.)

Comment: What about "1.0 meaters"? I thought 1.0 is equal to 1, so it should be “1.0 meter”.

Comment: Both "two thirds meters" and "two thirds meter" sound very wrong to me. I agree with your suggested *two thirds of a meter*, and you're correct about using the singular when the number is 1, but... I can't get behind *two thirds meter(s)*.

Comment: I think both "1.0 meters" and "1.0 meter" work.

Comment: [Should we use plural or singular for a fraction of a mile?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44489/is-1-0-singular-or-plural) 1.0 may not exactly be one.

Comment: I would definitely prefer "a quarter of a meter" over "a quarter meter" and any other of your 'common fractions'; about the only time I wouldn't say "of a" is for *half*, and then I'd say "half a meter".

Comment: In general, when one sees 1.0 written, it refers to something that is not exact. For example: we would never say "The number of people in that room is 1.0", as one doesn't usually have fractional people. 1.0 means that as best we can tell there are somewhere between .95 and 1.049 of the thing we're measuring, but it is not exactly one necessarily.